# How to create union type from enum numeric values?

Tags: typescript

From enum:

```
enum Weekdays {
  Monday = 1,
  Tuesday = 2
}
```

We would like to get this type:

```
type WeekdaysType = 1 | 2
```

Comment: `Weekdays` itself is that union.

Comment: Not really. It looks like type widening happens and resulting type is a number:
```

enum Weekdays {
  Monday = 1,
  Tuesday = 2,
};

const c: Weekdays = 5  // no error

```

Comment: If you are inspecting the values of an `enum` you probably don't want an `enum`.  Why not change it to `const Weekdays = {Monday: 1, Tuesday: 2} as const; type WeekDays = (typeof Weekdays)[keyof typeof Weekdays]` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WK8Myw)?  What is the use case here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, instead of the numeric enum, you create a `const` object whose prototypes correspond to the numeric values your original `enum` had:

```
const Weekdays = {
  Monday: 1,
  Tuesday: 2,
} as const;
```

Then, you can define a type with the same name as the object above:

```
type Weekdays = (typeof Weekdays)[keyof typeof Weekdays];
```

This type is the union of the types of the object properties, i.e., `1 | 2`. That's why you need the `as const` assertion above so that TypeScript infers the literal types `1` and `2` for `Monday` and `Tuesday,` respectively. Otherwise, it would infer the broader type `number` and the type `Weekdays` would result in `number` as a consequence.

Both `typeof`s aren't JavaScript's `typeof` despite taking a value (i.e., the `const` object) as their operand. They correspond to TypeScript's `typeof` because they are being used in the *type space* (they are inside a type definition):

```
type Weekdays = (typeof Weekdays)[keyof typeof Weekdays];
                 ^^^^^^                 ^^^^^^
```

Finally, note that in this solution, you have both a type and a value with the name `Weekdays`: the type `Weekdays` and the `const` object `Weekdays`. There are no clashing issues here since they live in different spaces: the type and value spaces.

Comment: Accepting as this is closest to what is wanted.

Answer (score 0):

With [TypeScript 4.1+](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#template-literal-types), you can use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html):

```
enum Weekdays {
  Monday = 1,
  Tuesday = 2,
};

type WeekdaysType = `${Weekdays}`;
```

Caveat: This only works with enums that have string values, so for your particular use case, `WeekdaysType` would be `"1" | "2"`, rather than `1 | 2`. As far as I'm aware, there's no current way to dynamically extract numeric enum values into a union type.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=29&pln=8&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBA6swGsAmBDAngZygbwFBSgFkB7EVNKAXigEYAafKAFTGA3KqgCYGBfAbly4ALmgAOwWPGToMTcZOoADACTY4ichl5LBuAMakMwqADNixAFxTNs+RM4AiGo8GGQxqACMUAJ2saMpj2irRuRiY+AF4B0lohnADM-EA)

Comment: Does not work as created type is: `type WeekdaysType = "1" | "2"`

Comment: Please see my edit with the caveat. As far as I'm aware, as of TS 4.4, there's no way to get a union type from **numeric** enum values.

Comment: Also, I don't believe there's any way to convert a string literal type to a numeric literal type dynamically.

Comment: All this does is convert to string; the original type already *is* the union of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```js
enum Code {
    a = 111,
    b = 222,
    c = 'abc'
}

type StrToNum<Str> =
  Str extends `${infer Num extends number}`
    ? Num
    : Str

type res = StrToNum<`${Code}`>;
```

Comment: Type of res is: `type res = number | "abc"` what I would like to have is type `res = 111 | 222 | "abc"`.

Comment: asker is only asking about numeric values. why do you have a string :p

Answer (score -1):

### Instead enum, you can use union types

```
const Weekdays {
  Monday: 1,
  Tuesday: 2,
} as const;

type Union<T> = T[keyof T];

type WeekdaysType = Union<typeof Weekdays>; // type WeekdaysType = 1 | 2

// you can use like enum
console.log(Weekdays.Monday) // 1
```

### Numeric enums are not type safe

```
enum ZeroOrOne {
  Zero = 0,
  One = 1
}
const zeroOrOne: ZeroOrOne = 2; // no error!!
```

Comment: it should produce an error 0_o
At least it produces for me